# How to solve Output argument (and maybe others) not assigned during call

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I'm trying to write a script that achieves the following:

1. Loop over each pixel in a dicom image.
2. If the pixel value exceeds a user-defined threshold (t1) then:
    Overlay a filter kernel/block of user-defined size.
    Find a percentile (t2) of all values in the block/kernel.
    Find the mean of all pixels in the block that are less than t2.
    Replace the original pixel > t1 with the mean of those less than the t2 
    percentile.

I've tried using the blockproc function for this as follows:

```
function bkgdsub()
clc;

dimX = 5;        %Size of the kernel/block 
dimY = dimX;

bfmap = dicomread('IM8');
myfilter = @filter;

subimg = blockproc(bfmap, [dimX dimY], myfilter, 'PadPartialBlocks', false);
imshow(subimg)

end

function subtract = filter(block_struct)

dimX = 5;          %Set the 2D size of the kernel footprint (z, y).
dimY = dimX;
t1 = 100;   %Set threshold 1 (t1) 
t2 = 75;     %Set percentile threshold (t2)

avg = [];
singlevalue = ones([dimX dimY]);

for n = 1:dimX
    for m = 1:dimY
        if block_struct.data(n,m) >= t1;

            pc = prctile(blockstruct.data, t2)

                for i = 1:size(blockstruct.data, 1)
                    for j = 1:size(blockstruct.data, 2)
                        if blockstruct.data(i, j) < pc
                            avg = [avg blockstruct.data(i, j)];
                        end
                    end
                end

            avgMn = mean(avg(:))

            singlevalue(n,m) = avgMn
        end
    end
end
end
```

I run into the following errors:

> Function BLOCKPROC encountered an error while evaluating the user
>   supplied function handle, FUN.
>
> The cause of the error was:
>
> Output argument "subtract" (and maybe others) not assigned during call
>   to "C:...\test.m>filter".
>
> Error in blockprocFunDispatcher (line 14)
>           output_block = fun(block_struct);
>
> Error in blockprocInMemory (line 81) [ul_output fun_nargout] =
>   blockprocFunDispatcher(fun,block_struct,...
>
> Error in blockproc (line 237)
>       result_image = blockprocInMemory(source,fun,options);
>
> Error in bfsubtract2 (line 15) subimg = blockproc(bfmap, [dimX dimY],
>   myfilter, 'PadPartialBlocks', false);

Any thoughts on how I could tackle this?  Any insight into these errors with using blockproc is also appreciated.

Tx.

Answer (score 0):

You should read your error message carefully:

> Output argument **"subtract"** (and maybe others) not assigned during call to **filter**

So, the solution is to define `subtract` inside `filter` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be easier to implement with nlfilter.  Code block below if anyone needs it in the future.

```
function main()
clc;            %Clear the command window

dimX = 3;       %Set the 2D size of the kernel footprint (z, y).
dimY = dimX;
w = [dimY dimX];

t1 = 100;       %Set threshold 1 (BF) 
t2 = 75;        %Set percentile threshold 


%kernel1=ones(5, 5)

kernel = xlsread('testgrid.xlsx')   %loads in the test matrix from first sheet of excel file

bfmap = dicomread('IM8');

fun = @windfilt;

Subtract = nlfilter(kernel, w, fun)



end 

function y = windfilt(A)

    t1 = 7;
    t2 = 75;
    avg = [];

    [m, n] = size(A);

    if A(2, 2) >= t1             %Set back to t1
        pc = prctile(A(:), t2);

        for i = 1:size(A, 1)
            for j = 1:size(A, 2)
                if ((A(i, j) <= pc) & (A(i, j) ~= 0))     
                    avg = [avg A(i, j)];
                end
            end
        end

        y = median(avg(:));
        clear avg

    else          
        y = A(2, 2);      %Set y = to the center pixel value if ~> t1
    end

end
```